# Is there a way to use Clear() without typing Console before it?

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can use a command line like Clear(), instead of Console.Clear(), to be a bit faster? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you look for [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)?

Comment: Yes, add `using static System.Console`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static

Comment: You can also make your own Clear method. But the real question is, _why?_ Does that really benefit you?

Comment: It's just a bit faster.

Comment: Faster to type? asking this question was pretty expensive, imo..?

Comment: with 0 downvotes??